# Blazor Valued changed while keeping 2-way binding

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there anyway to keep 2-way binding, as well as have a method called on @onchange?

Something like this.

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="My Number" @bind="Record.Number"  @onchange="(()=> MyMethod())">
```

I'd like it to bind , but on change call some other method that isn't going to be setting the Record.Number value from the change events.

@onkeyup works, but I'd like to make sure the value actually changes.

Comment: Presumably Record.Number is a C# property.  Why not put your onchange code there?

Comment: Its tough to put it in there, its a separate model that isn't directly in the page model. The Page Model has a property called 'Record', which has tons of property related to the record. So the Record property doesn't have access to the Page Model methods.

Comment: Fair enough.  Does hooking up `OnChange` actually screw up the binding?  I would imagine that both mechanisms should still work.

Comment: Yes unfortunately. If you have onchange, you can't use @bind, and have to use value='Record.Number', and it doesn't set the property when it changes anymore, and you must set it in the method used in onchange. There might not be a easy way, might have to just put my properties directly in the Page model, was hoping I didn't have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="My Number" @bind="Record.Number"  
   @onchange="(()=> MyMethod())">
```

Can be expressed another way:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="My Number" value="@record.Number" 
            @onchange="@((args) => { record.Number = args.Value.ToString(); 
            MyMethod();})"/>
```

This creates a two-way binding where the input value is updated in the bound field (record.Number) as the 'change' event is triggered (this always occurs when you tab out of the control). Additionally, a call is made to the MyMethod method(used here to demonstrate that the value has been changed, and the timing (tabbing out of the control).

Here's a working example:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="My Number" value="@record.Number" 
            @onchange="@((args) => { record.Number = args.Value.ToString(); MyMethod();})">
<p>@output</p>

@code {

    private static string output;
 private void MyMethod()
    {
        output = record.Number;
    }
    Record record = new Record();

    public class Record
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is probably the best its going to get. Thanks

Comment: Could you guys use another name than record which is a reserved keyword in c# now?